# React router not rerendering after state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have such react component with router. That will render login page if login passed by props is false. Props are fueled by redux state.

```
const Root = ({logged, history}) => {
  console.log(logged);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ATM} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
      //Removed without effect-->{!logged ? <Redirect to="/login"/> : ""}
    </div>
  )
};

const fromState = (state) => ({
  logged: state.auth.logged
});

export default connect(fromState)(Root)
```

In my login component I have hacked a call that will ask server whether user has successfully authed and redirect if that's the case.

```
this.props.dispatch(action).then((result) => {
  let responseCode = result.payload.status;
  if(responseCode === 200) {
    this.props.dispatch(push("/"))
  }
})
```

In my App I have defined history as such:

```
let blankHistory = createHistory();
let store = storeCreator(blankHistory);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(blankHistory,store );
```

Store creator applies middlewares and reducers, takes history as an argument because routerMiddleware needs it.

After that is called state is changing, logged becomes true, path in my browser is changing, history object is aware of that path change, but I still see rendered Login component and `console.log(logged)` is not being called second time.

Does anyone one know what is actually the problem?

--EDIT--
After a bit of investigation I added this bit code to init:

```
let history = syncHistoryWithStore(blankHistory,store );
console.log(history.location)
history.listen((something) => {
  console.log(something)
});
```

And history in first log has correct path, but immedietaly after that History receives pathname: "/" and that might be cause of the problem.

Comment: First problem I can see is having `<Redirect/>` outside of `<Router/>` component. Try moving it inside `<Router/>` and then check if still have a problem.

Comment: I still have problem if I remove that rediret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lied in incompatible versions of `react-redux-router` and `react-router`. I've Updated first one and It works like a charm.